# Python Overridden __add__ Doesn't Work for a += b

Tags: python, operator-overloading, overriding

I've been working on a Vector object class to allow me to solve math problems quickly using Python.

**For Example:**
If we set `vector = Vector(1, 2, 3)` and we run `vector *= 2`, then vector will be equal to `<2, 4, 6>`

**The Issue:** Whenever I run `vector += 2`, it errors saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Math\matrices.py", line 149, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Math\matrices.py", line 139, in main
    vector += 2
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my **Vector class**

```
class Vector(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        for arg in args:
            self.append(arg)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, float) or isinstance(other, int)
        return Vector(*[row * other for row in self])

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, float) or isinstance(other, int)
        return Vector(*[row / other for row in self])

    def __add__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, float) or isinstance(other, int)
        print(type(other))
        return Vector(*[row + other for row in self])

    def __sub__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, float) or isinstance(other, int)
        return Vector(*[row - other for row in self])

    def __str__(self):
        return "<" + ", ".join([str(e) for e in self]) + ">"
```

Here is my **main function**

```
def main():
    vector = Vector(1, 2, 3)
    vector *= 2
    print(vector)
    vector += 2
    print(vector)
```

**What I've done to find the solution:**

- I've tried to do `vector = vector + 2` and that works, but I would
  rather understand why it's not working and be able to fix it.
- I've tried googling how operator overloading works in Python
- I've tried looking through operator overloading threads on StackOverflow, but I don't see any that answer my question. They're all about how a = a + b, not a += b.
- I've tried using **iadd**, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `__iadd__` should work... You can even just write `__iadd__ = __add__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the line `__iadd__ = __add__`:

```py
class Vector(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        for arg in args:
            self.append(arg)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, float) or isinstance(other, int)
        return Vector(*[row * other for row in self])

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, float) or isinstance(other, int)
        return Vector(*[row / other for row in self])

    def __add__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, float) or isinstance(other, int)
        print(type(other))
        return Vector(*[row + other for row in self])

    __iadd__ = __add__

    def __sub__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, float) or isinstance(other, int)
        return Vector(*[row - other for row in self])

    def __str__(self):
        return "<" + ", ".join([str(e) for e in self]) + ">"


vector = Vector(1, 2, 3)
vector *= 2
print(vector)
vector += 2
print(vector)
```

Prints:

```
<2, 4, 6>
<class 'int'>
<4, 6, 8>
```

Comment: Actually you were right, I was just running an old version of the file. THANK YOU SO MUCH!